# do we observe emission spectrum?

Tags: star, galaxy, universe, radiation, electromagnetic-spectrum

When light generated by the fusion in the sun goes through the layers of the sun and finally reaches outer layers and in the end atmosphere of the sun, we know it goes through hydrogen for example. Once it goes through it, some wavelengths will be absorbed, and others will just be transmitted(those who were not absorbed). So the light we get on earth from sun - we call it absorption spectrum but we also should be getting emission spectrum(separately) due to hydrogen’s electrons releasing energies. Does this mean we get 2 different lights from the sun ? Note that They wouldn’t arrive to us at the same time as definitely transmitted ones would quickly transmit, while absorbed ones(before they get absorbed and then releasing again) would happen a little bit later, maybe after a sec. So we should be getting 2 different spectrums.

Is this true ? and if so, we only observe absorption spectrum and don't care about emission spectrum ?

Comment: See also https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/2174/the-formation-of-absorption-lines-in-solar-spectrum